# Problem with loading Javascript files in a Django/Ext JS 4 based application

Tags: django, extjs4

I'm trying to get this [Extjs4 guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture) working with Django 1.3. I managed to get it working without Django with just a static json file as the data store.

Then I took the following approach to make it work with a Django app.

- First I created a Django app named `userdb` with a simple User model(only a `username` and an `email` field).
- Then I created two views in Django First one(`mysite.com/users/`) is a `TemplateView` which just directs to the index.html template file. The second one(`mysite.com/users/getusers`) produces a json response exactly like one in `users.json` file in the guide.
- I have a directory project-static in Django project directory where I put all my static files. So I created `project-static/userdb/extjs/` and put all the sdk files there. `project-static/userdb` also contains all the JS files I created for the Ext JS app in the guide.
- Then I modified the `Users.js` in `app/store/` to use the url of the `getusers` view.
- After that I collected all the static resources to a static folder using `python manage.py collectstatic` to be served via `mysite.com/static/`.

When I visit `mysite.com/users/` all the JS files of Ext JS loads fine, But the JS files I wrote for the app doesn't load because Ext JS does not load them from `mysite.com/static/` instead it uses `mysite.com/users/`. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized while reading this [blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-ext-loader-for-your-application/) that the problem was with the loader not using the /static path of my application. So i needed to do the following to resolve the issue,

in `index.html`,

```
    <html>

      {% load static %}
      <head>
        <title>Account Manager</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}userdb/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}userdb/extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}userdb/app.js"></script>

        <!-- This is Required before the loader starts, so we have to manually include it -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% get_static_prefix %}userdb/app/controller/Users.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
```

Then in `app.js` at the begining of the file,

```
Ext.Loader.setPath('AM', '/static/userdb/app');
```